# Optimal grid trading strategy when price out of grid bounds

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, binance, ccxt

I'm considering various grid trading strategies and I'm wondering what's the optimal action (if any) to take when the price goes out of grid bounds.

In the image below, the price is within a size 4 grid, with 2 buys below and 2 sells above.

[image: grid]

Say the price goes above the highest buy or below the lowest sell. If that happens, one can:

- Do nothing, and hope that the price goes back into grid bounds.
- Set a stop loss or take profit and cancel the grid when they trigger.
- Lowering or raising the grid. Price can thus be closer to the grid or inside it.

I can't think of any other ways right now. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I designed a new trading strategy called bollmaker in order to overcome the drawbacks of grid trading -- price range issue.

check this out, it's an open source strategy:

https://medium.com/bbgo/bbgo-bollmaker-trading-strategy-3a4e80b482e3